# Using C++ function as an argument in another C++ function in R package "Rcpp"

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am new in using R package "Rcpp". My question is, if I want to use a C++ function as an argument in another C++ function, how will I do that? For example: suppose I have an C++ function like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double maxllC3(const double mu){
 double result;
 result= R::dgamma(mu,0.1,1,0.1);
 return result;
 }
```

. I want to use this function in another C++ function like we can do this in R:

```
sumf<-function(maxllC3,mu,y){
  res<-maxllC3(mu)+y
  return(res)
}
```

. How can I do that in "Rcpp" package?

Comment: I don't understand why the first function needs to be passed as an argument to the second function.

Comment: @Roland hi Roland, it's just an example. I will apply this for much complicated example.

Comment: So, the user is supposed to pass a C++ function as an argument when calling the second function from R? That's unusual. I suspect an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Roland, NO. The C++ function will be used as an argument in second C++ function. I wrote the second code in R just to show how we use arguments in R.

Comment: Then it is totally unclear why it needs to be an argument. C++ is *not* a functional language. The only reason to pass it as an argument would be if the user needs to control which function is called within the second function. And that would happen from R.

Comment: @ Roland Then shall I just write C++ functions separately and then convert them to R using Rcpp and then use the first one as an argument to the second?

Answer (score -1):

- put you rcpp code in an .cpp file (say `ex.cpp`).
- use `Rcpp::sourceCpp('ex.cpp')` to make this function available in the global environment
- then just use `sumf <- function(mu, y) maxllC3(mu) + y`

Comment: @gultu If you're okay with the answer, you can validate it.